# How to avoid `out` parameter error when using intrinsics?

Tags: c#, .net-core, intrinsics, out

I am trying out the new hardware intrinsics added to .NET Core 3.0, specifically in order to accelerate operations on matrices. For matrix addition, I have a function, which takes two 4x4 `float` matrices as `in` parameters, and a third `out` matrix to store the results in. It uses the SSE 128-bit vector intrinsics to add and store the results in the output:

```cs
public unsafe static void Add(in Matrix l, in Matrix r, out Matrix o)
{
    fixed (float* lp = &l.m00, rp = &r.m00, op = &o.m00)
    {
        var c1 = Sse.Add(Sse.LoadVector128(lp + 0),  Sse.LoadVector128(rp + 0));
        var c2 = Sse.Add(Sse.LoadVector128(lp + 4),  Sse.LoadVector128(rp + 4));
        var c3 = Sse.Add(Sse.LoadVector128(lp + 8),  Sse.LoadVector128(rp + 8));
        var c4 = Sse.Add(Sse.LoadVector128(lp + 12), Sse.LoadVector128(rp + 12));
        Sse.Store(op + 0,  c1);
        Sse.Store(op + 4,  c2);
        Sse.Store(op + 8,  c3);
        Sse.Store(op + 12, c4);
    }
}
```

Now obviously the C# compiler has an issue with this, because it can't tell that the output matrix is ever written to, so it generates the error that the function cannot return until the `o` variable is assigned to. **My question is if there is any way around this**, without having to resort to assigning to the variable before performing the intrinsics operations, such as `o = default;` as the first line in the function.

I originally considered something along the lines of:

```cs
var op = stackalloc float[16];
fixed (float* lp = &l.m00, rp = &r.m00)
{
...
}
o = *(Matrix*)op;
```

but realized this doesn't avoid copying the struct, which removes the whole point of passing the matrix as an `out`.

I realize that this would work if I passed the output Matrix as `ref` instead, or if I just returned a matrix instance from the function, but it would be nice to keep the helpful inline syntax (`Matrix.Add(l, r, out Matrix o)`) and performance benefits from passing around large value types by reference.

Comment: Simple answer; no. `C#` requires all `out` parameters be initialized.

Comment: I am afraid, but accepting, that this is likely the case. I'm more curious if there are any tricks people may have up their sleeves to get around this specific issue.

Comment: Does using `out` not copy the struct? _I honestly don't know the answer._

Comment: @mjwills In the case of value types, an `out` parameter will pass a reference to a block of memory for that type, which can be written directly into. This removes the need for the struct copy when the function returns.

Comment: For what it's worth, I consider the inline declaration syntax to be of _very_ minimal benefit. I like using it when I can, but it is not even close to a serious inconvenience to not have access to it. That said, note that even if you use `ref`, you will be required to initialize the object. It's just that you have to initialize it before calling your method instead of inside it. Have you considered just initializing it with `new Matrix()`? I would guess that the compiler would optimize that reasonably well (if not csc, then the JIT compiler)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming here that you are using a `Matrix` type that is a `struct`. Obviously, if it were a reference type, then your method would in fact have to initialize the parameter value before you could use it, so the fact that your code doesn't indicates to me that it's a value type.

The C# compiler cannot be made to ignore compile-time errors. And it's a compile-time error to not initialize an `out` parameter before the method returns. So you are stuck.

That said, I don't think this should be a significant hardship. You can write your method as so:

```cs
public unsafe static void Add(in Matrix l, in Matrix r, out Matrix o)
{
    o = default(Matrix);

    fixed (float* lp = &l.m00, rp = &r.m00, op = &o.m00)
    {
        var c1 = Sse.Add(Sse.LoadVector128(lp + 0),  Sse.LoadVector128(rp + 0));
        var c2 = Sse.Add(Sse.LoadVector128(lp + 4),  Sse.LoadVector128(rp + 4));
        var c3 = Sse.Add(Sse.LoadVector128(lp + 8),  Sse.LoadVector128(rp + 8));
        var c4 = Sse.Add(Sse.LoadVector128(lp + 12), Sse.LoadVector128(rp + 12));
        Sse.Store(op + 0,  c1);
        Sse.Store(op + 4,  c2);
        Sse.Store(op + 8,  c3);
        Sse.Store(op + 12, c4);
    }
}
```

This will compile to something like this (I picked an arbitrary `Matrix` type for the sake of the example…it's obviously not the one you're using, but the basic premise is the same):

```
IL_0000:  ldarg.0
IL_0001:  initobj    System.Windows.Media.Matrix
```

Which in turn will simply [initialize the block of memory to `0` values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.initobj):

> The `initobj` instruction initializes each field of the value type specified by the pushed address (of type `native int`, `&`, or `*`) to a null reference or a 0 of the appropriate primitive type. After this method is called, the instance is ready for a constructor method to be called. If `typeTok` is a reference type, this instruction has the same effect as `ldnull` followed by `stind.ref`.
>
> Unlike `Newobj`, `initobj` does not call the constructor method. `Initobj` is intended for initializing value types, while `newobj` is used to allocate and initialize objects.

In other words, `initobj`, which is what you get when you use `default(Matrix)`, is a very simple initialization, merely zeroing out the memory location. It should be fast enough, and in any case is obviously less overhead than allocating a whole new copy of the object and then copying the result back to the original variable, whether that's done locally or via return value.

All that said, this depends a lot on the context of how you're going to call the method. While you say that you would like to preserve the convenience of inline declaration, it's not clear to me why you would want that for a method that is apparently performance-critical enough to be using SSE features and unsafe code. With inline declaration, you necessarily are going to have to reinitialize the variable with each call.

If this method is actually being called in a performance-critical way, then to me that implies it's in a loop being called a large number of times, possibly millions or more. In that situation, you may prefer the `ref` option, where you can initialize the variable outside you loop, and then just reuse that variable for each call, rather than redeclaring a new variable for each call.

Comment: *merely zeroing out the memory location. It should be fast enough*...  Perhaps you're not realizing how cheap the real work of this function is.  If the zeroing doesn't optimize away once it gets to the real optimizer, another 4 `movups` instructions is a significant fraction of the total uop count for this function.  e.g. 4x `movups` load, 4x `addps` with memory sources (assuming aligned source or if AVX is available), 4x `movups` stores.  So 12 fused-domain uops. Zeroing a register and doing another 4 stores would bring it up to 17 uops. Also store throughput is only 1/clock (until Icelake)

Comment: The analysis is basically identical for AMD and Intel, except that AMD can't do 2 load + 1 store per clock.  If this function inlines into the caller where the data is already in registers, it's just 4x `addps` without necessarily storing, e.g. if the 4x4 matrix is going to be an input to something else.  And BTW, if the matrix was large, writing it twice would be even *more* expensive.  (e.g. if the stores might miss in cache, then both passes would pay that cost.)  So this answer is only good if you can show that the dummy init optimizes away in practice.

Comment: @Peter: thanks. My answer is presented from the point of view of the higher-level C# issues. The OP says they want to use inline declaration of the parameter, and it's not clear whether they even really need performance here. It's beyond my intended scope to dig very deeply into the nitty gritty of counting cycles; rather, to focus on the C# abstractions that are available vs those which are not. If you find the answer lacking, I encourage you to post your own so that the OP can benefit from your wisdom.

Comment: If I had a C# compiler and knew the language, I might check it out.  But I don't so I can't easily investigate.  If the OP didn't need performance, presumably they wouldn't be manually using SIMD.  Anyway, *hopefully* you just need to keep the language happy, and real compilers will optimize away the store/reload to memory entirely if possible, when optimizing for CIL to machine code after inlining.  If that's plausible, I'd phrase the answer that way, not in terms of zeroing have a small but negligible cost.

Comment: Anyway, doesn't C# have a `Vector<float>` extension that lets you do SIMD without `unsafe` code?  That might be a better idea, and gives you 256-bit vectors on machines that support them.  Unless the OP needs this style of using SSE for shuffles to transpose matrices?  IDK enough about how C# exposes SIMD; I just sometimes look at C# simd questions because sometimes they're about what x86 can do efficiently, assuming there's a way to express that in C# somehow.

Comment: @peter: .NET (C#) has a whole `System.Numerics` namespace with optimized numerical data types. There's not enough context in the question to know if that's an option for the OP, or if that's really even what they want. Maybe the use of SSE here is academic exercise. The question isn't presented as a performance issue but rather a "make the compiler happy" issue, and so I've answered in that vein.

Comment: Sure.  My only objection to your answer is that you suggest a non-zero overhead is probably ok, instead of suggesting that this might optimize away entirely.  (Or maybe it can't, IDK if boundaries between unsafe and managed code are a problem for the optimizer, in which case doing this tiny amount of work inside an unsafe function might be a bad idea).  The rest of it, explaining why you have to keep the compiler happy and so on, looks good.

Comment: @PeterDuniho, thank you for the analysis of the generated IL, its helpful in seeing exactly what the C# compiler is doing in the background. I am going to do some more timing tests to see if the overhead of the `default(Matrix)` still allows the SSE instructions to be faster than a member-wise addition.

Comment: @PeterCordes, thanks for the additional information as well, in terms of the nitty-gritty level of counting cycles. My interest in this issue is academic, and my original question was intended to get around the peculiarities of the C# compiler. However, it's nice to have an analysis of the really low level.